# Is there a good CSV parser for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, csv

I have a csv file which contains set of product details with their prices. I need to parse this csv file to perform some search queries.

Yes, I tried https://github.com/ha-minh-vuong/CSVParser but this library fails when parsing product prices. because in my CSV product price contains a comma.

"12,500.00"

P.S : Line separator must be a comma coz I'm getting this CSV directly from the client. I can't change anything

#### Update:

sample line
DSK0009, HL , 0.02 , HQ , F , AI2 ,-,-,-,-,Pink,-,-,"12,500.00","1,150.00"

Comment: This is going to be on of those tricky ones. Can you paste one whole sample row of data that you might want to parse? Does every column of data is guarded by "" and separated by comma?

Comment: @Bugivore, Thank you for the response. I have updated my question with a sample line.

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama Ask your client to change seperater from comma(,) to anything else like Pie(|) or tsv means (Tab Seperated values) etc

Comment: @Thilina - Let me test out a piece of code and get back..

Comment: @Thilina - Instead of relying on third party library, I have simple code which takes care of parsing.. Unfortunately I am not able to add answer probably bcoz you accepted the answer or question has been put on hold...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want the one by Dave DeLong. It's on github. It's the goto CSV library

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'll try this and let you know the result

Comment: Like I said, it's the goto library. Everybody loves it, and Dave does good work.

Comment: Dave writes good stuff, absolutely. Go forth and upvote some of his answers too as a thanks (they're generally worth it).

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex patterns

```
NSString *source = @"DSK0009, HL , 0.02 , HQ , F , AI2 ,-,-,-,-,Pink,-,-,\"12,500.00\",\"1,150.00\"";
NSString *pattern = @"(?:^|,)\"?((?<=\")[^\"]*|[^,\"]*)\"?(?=,|$)";
NSRegularExpression *nameExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [nameExpression matchesInString:source
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [source length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *matchString = [source substringWithRange:matchRange];
    NSLog(@"%@", matchString);
}
```